# Compare Two different arrays and update array of objects with useState in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, use-state

So I have an array called `preferredMeetingDays`:

```
const preferredMeetingDays = ["Mon", "Tue"];
```

I have an array of days called `chosenDays`:

```
const chosenDays = [
  {
    id: "Sun",
    dayValue: "Sun",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Mon",
    dayValue: "Mon",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Tue",
    dayValue: "Tue",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Wed",
    dayValue: "Wed",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Thu",
    dayValue: "Thu",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Fri",
    dayValue: "Fri",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Sat",
    dayValue: "Sat",
    chosen: false
  }
]
```

The `chosenDays` array is used with useState like:

```
const [isChosenDays, setIsChosenDays] = useState(chosenDays);
```

What I want to do is compare the `preferredMeetingDays` array with the `isChosenDays` state and change the `chosen` key value of a single day object to `true` if the day object in `isChosenDays` is present in `preferredMeetingDays` array. In this case, that would be `"Mon"` and `"Tue"`. The new `isChosenDays` state would be:

```
[
  {
    id: "Sun",
    dayValue: "Sun",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Mon",
    dayValue: "Mon",
    chosen: true
  },
  {
    id: "Tue",
    dayValue: "Tue",
    chosen: true
  },
  {
    id: "Wed",
    dayValue: "Wed",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Thu",
    dayValue: "Thu",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Fri",
    dayValue: "Fri",
    chosen: false
  },
  {
    id: "Sat",
    dayValue: "Sat",
    chosen: false
  }
]
```

I have tried this code but it is not working and adding `undefined` to the array:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(preferredMeetingDays.length > 0) {
      setIsChosenDays(isChosenDays => [
        ...isChosenDays,
        ...preferredMeetingDays.map((preferredDay) => {
          isChosenDays.map(chosenDay => {
            if(chosenDay.id === preferredDay) {
              return {
                ...chosenDay,
                chosen: true
              }
            }
            return chosenDay;
          })
        }),
      ])
    }
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])
```

How do I get this to work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
useEffect(() => {
    setIsChosenDays(
      isChosenDays.map((day) => {
        if (preferredMeetingDays.some((pDay) => pDay === day.id)) {
          day.chosen = true;
          return day;
        } 
        return day;
        
      })
    );
  }, []);
```

[here is a working example codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-moon-4z7rd8?file=/src/App.js)